# "Region with the given name is already registered" after navigating from Module in Prism for Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism, region

(I'd just like to say I have a workaround for this using the `EventAggregator` - as seen at the bottom of the post - but I'd like to get to the bottom of why it is not working the way I have it currently set up).

I have a Xamarin Forms application in which I am using Prism (Version 8) for Xamarin Forms (Version 4.8).
In this application I am using Modules and Regions for Forms.

My main application has a `MainPage` (in a `NavigationPage`) in which I have a Prism Region into which Views are injected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestPrismModules.Views.MainPage"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             Title="{Binding Title}">

            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                    <FlexLayout prism:RegionManager.RegionName="FlexRegion"/>
            </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

I have a Module (AuthModule) which handles Authentication and Logging in via an `AuthenticationService`.
This Module also contains a `LoginPage` with equivelant `LoginPageViewModel`. The `Logout` method in the `AuthenticationService` does the logging out and does a `NavigateAsync` to the `LoginPage`

```
public class AuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{
    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;

    public AuthenticationService(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }

    public void Logout()
    {
        // logging out code goes here
        _navigationService.NavigateAsync("/LoginPage");
    }
}
```

This is the AuthModule Module code:

```
public class AuthModuleModule : IModule
{
    public void OnInitialized(IContainerProvider containerProvider)
    {
    }

    public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.Register<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterRegionServices();
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<LoginPage, LoginPageViewModel>();
    }
}
```

Upon launching the application, the first page navigated to is the `LoginPage` (reminder - in the AuthModule). So far so good.

I have a requirement that if a user deactivates the application momentarily at all that once it resumes or is reactivated the user is logged out and has to log in again. To this end I override the `OnResume` method, resolve an instance of my `AuthenticationService` and call the `Logout` method therein.

```
public partial class App
{
    public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer)
        : base(initializer)
    {
    }

    protected override async void OnInitialized()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var ea = Container.Resolve<IEventAggregator>();
        ea.GetEvent<LoggedInEvent>().Subscribe(OnUserAuthenticated);
        await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/LoginPage",null,true,true);
    }

    private void OnUserAuthenticated()
    {
        NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/NavigationPage/MainPage");
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {

        containerRegistry.RegisterRegionServices();
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IAppInfo, AppInfoImplementation>();

        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MainPage, MainPageViewModel>();
        
    }

    protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog(IModuleCatalog moduleCatalog)
    {
        base.ConfigureModuleCatalog(moduleCatalog);
        moduleCatalog.AddModule<TestModule1Module>();
        moduleCatalog.AddModule<AuthModuleModule>();
    }


    // Want to force user to login when the app resumes
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();

        // Logout and redirect to Login Page
        var authService = Container.Resolve<IAuthenticationService>();
        authService.Logout();
    }
 }
```

This ALL works fine and dandy - until the user tries to log in again and they get the dreaded "**Region with the given name is already registered**

Navigating to the `LoginPage` directly from the main application (rather than through the `AuthenticationService`), and back to the `MainPage` after logging back in, works fine and I don't get the exception about the Region already being registered. Knowing that, I have a workaround where I use the `EventAggregator` to Subscribe to a `LoggedOut` event (in the `App.xaml.cs`) and publish that event from the `AuthenticationService` and call the `NavigateAsync` from the subscription.

I suspect I might get suggestions on using Scoped regions or some such but I'm not sure how to go about that.

I have a sample project available here to test if it helps: https://github.com/tomaswinston/TestPrismModulesAuth

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am getting this error and I can't figure out how to deal with it.

Comment: @jmichas No. Never got it sorted. I was working on the project as a proof of concept and haven't been working on it for the last number of months. I thought I had logged an issue on Prism GitHub but seemingly not. It might be worth doing so, with a sample project.  As I mentioned above my workaround was to publish an EventAggregator event from my AuthenticationService and subscribe to that event in my App.Xaml.cs - whereupon I call NavigationService.NavigateAsync. That worked for me.